# How to create Recoil MutableSnapshot?

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

According to the Docs,
https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/RecoilRoot

`<RecoilRoot>` accept props as `initializeState?: (MutableSnapshot => void)` signature.
That able to initialize Recoil State so I want to use this props but I don't understand how to make `MutableSnapshot` object.

```
import {RecoilRoot} from 'recoil';

function AppRoot() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot initializeState={/* How to setup arguments here? */} >
      <ComponentThatUsesRecoil />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

On the other hand `Snapshot` is easier to get from `useRecoilSnapshot()` though.

Comment: You can check out how `MutableSnapshot` is built up here in the source code: https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/blob/master/typescript/index.d.ts#L81
Or you can check out recoil-persist, how they did it https://github.com/polemius/recoil-persist/blob/master/index.js#L36

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure out answer of the question myself.
MutableSnapshot is passed by Recoil library code automatically so user don't have to create MutableSnapshot object yourself.

Bellow code is typically usage of initializeState.
Pick argument you need (set, get etc) form MutableSnapshot with object destructuring then write your state initialization code.

```
  render(
    <RecoilRoot
      initializeState={({ set }: MutableSnapshot): void =>
        set(recoilState, initialRecoilStateValue)
      }
    >
      {ui}
    </RecoilRoot>
  )
```